# Check for uniform convergence of the integral $\int\limits_{0}^{1}\frac{\arctan ax}{(1-x^2)^a}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals, uniform-convergence

Check for uniform convergence of the integral
$$\int\limits_{0}^{1}\frac{\arctan ax}{(1-x^2)^a}dx, \; a\in (-1,1)$$
My attempt was an evaluation, but I don't think it's right

$$\left| \int\limits_{0}^{1}\frac{\arctan ax}{(1-x^2)^a}dx \right| \leq \frac{\pi}{2} \int\limits_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{(1-x^2)^a}dx \leq \frac{\pi}{2} \int\limits_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{(1-x)^a}dx < \infty$$

Comment: I'm trying to justify the middle to right part of the inequality. I think if it works, then you can get an estimate independent of $a$.

Comment: That would be really great! And for $a\in \left [ -2,\frac{2}{3} \right ]$ could you also show an estimate?

Comment: Answer updated with steps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I can establish the estimate.

My first issue was, as I mentioned, the inequality from the center to the right. With $x \in (0, 1)$ we can establish that

$$ x^2 \leq x \implies \frac{1}{1-x^2} \leq \frac{1}{1-x}.$$

For the moment, I'll omit the justification (it's an exercise in inequality manipulations). Now, you already used the fact that $\arctan x \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$ for each $x$, so it remains to handle the right inequality. Observe that by the change of variable $x \mapsto 1-x$ the integral remains unchanged. Now,

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x^a} \ dx &= \frac{x^{-a+1}}{1-a}\Bigg|_0 ^1 \\
&= \frac{1}{1-a} \\
& \leq \frac{1}{2}. \\\
\end{align*}

Observe that the inequality in the last line is achieved by allowing $a \to -1^+$.

Upon writing this I've noticed that if $a \to 1^-$ then the integral can be made arbitrarily large. This may pose a problem - so I think it's safe to say that the original integral is uniformly convergent on $(-1, 1-\epsilon)$ where $\epsilon > 0.$ In fact, the left boundary can be allowed to go to $-\infty.$

TL:DR; So long as $a$ is an interval far enough away from $1$, say, for example $[-2, \frac{2}{3}]$, we have uniform convergence. No extra work needs to be shown for this.

Comment: Thank you so much! And could you show the estimate for $a\in \left [ -2,\frac{2}{3} \right ]$?

Comment: Yes -- as long as $a$ is bounded away from $1$ this shows that convergence is uniform.

Comment: Strangely enough, there is a divergence of opinion. You say that the integral converges on this interval, and the other person showed that it diverges

Comment: The issue is that we can't get arbitrarily close to $a = 1,$ because then the integral isn't convergent on an interval that includes $1.$ If we bound away from it enough, then we have uniform convergence.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the solution! Will it be possible to show the score for the second interval above?

Comment: That's already taken care of. No change is needed - notice my last sentence: " In fact, the left boundary can be allowed to go to $-\infty.$"

Comment: So for $a\in \left [ -2,\frac{2}{3} \right ]$ the integral will also converge?

Comment: I thought it was clear, but yes. Yes it does. $\frac{2}{3}$ is far enough away from the problem point. I encourage you to show this yourself.

Comment: Yes, thank you so much for the detailed explanations! Now I have it all figured out!

Answer (score 2):

If the integral converges uniformly, then (Cauchy criterion) for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta \in (0,1)$ such that for every $c_1,c_2$ such that $\delta < c_1 < c_2 < 1$ and every $a \in (-1,1)$ we would have

$$\tag{*}\left|\int_{c_1}^{c_2} \frac{\arctan ax}{(1-x^2)^a} \, dx \right| < \epsilon$$

For any such $\delta$, we can take $c_1 = (1-\frac{1}{n}) $, $c_2 = (1-\frac{1}{2n}) $ and $a_n = (1-\frac{1}{n}) $ and for all sufficiently large $n$ we have $c_1,c_2 \in (\delta ,1)$ and $a_n \in (-1,1)$. It follows that

$$\left|\int_{c_1}^{c_2} \frac{\arctan a_nx}{(1-x^2)^{a_n}} \, dx \right| = \int_{1-\frac{1}{n}}^{1 - \frac{1}{2n}} \frac{\arctan [(1-\frac{1}{n})x]}{(1-x^2)^{1 - \frac{1}{n}}} \, dx> \frac{1}{2n} \cdot\frac{\arctan [(1-\frac{1}{n})(1-\frac{1}{n})]}{\left(1-(1-\frac{1}{2n})^2\right)^{1-\frac{1}{n}}}\\ = \frac{1}{2}\frac{\arctan [(1-\frac{1}{n})^2]}{n\left(\frac{1}{n}- \frac{1}{4n^2}\right)^{1 - \frac{1}{n}}}= \frac{1}{2}\frac{\arctan [(1-\frac{1}{n})^2]}{\frac{n}{n^{1 - \frac{1}{n}}}\left(1- \frac{1}{4n}\right)^{1 - \frac{1}{n}}}= \frac{1}{2}\frac{\arctan [(1-\frac{1}{n})^2]}{n^{\frac{1}{n}}\left(1- \frac{1}{4n}\right)^{1 - \frac{1}{n}}}$$

The RHS converges to $\frac{\pi}{8}$ as $n \to \infty$ and must exceed $\frac{\pi}{16}$ for all sufficiently large $n$. This implies that the condition (*) for uniform convergence is violated when we take small values of $\epsilon > 0$.

Thus, the integral fails to converge uniformly for all $a \in (-1,1)$ with the problem arising because values of $a$ can be arbitrarily close to $1$.

Comment: Could you show an estimate for $a\in \left [ -2,\frac{2}{3} \right ]$?

Comment: @Partim: If $a$ is negative then there are no concerns. With $-2 < a < 0$ we have $1/(1-x^2)^a = (1-x^2)^{|a|} < 1$ and the constant $1$ is integrable. If $0 < a < 2/3$ then the approach in the other answer works to find an integrable bound.

Comment: Why is this assessment correct? What is it called, the inequality of the mean?
$\left||\int_{c_n}^1 \frac{\\arctan a_nx}{(1-x^2)^{a_n}} \, dx \right| = \int_{(1-1/n)}^1 \frac{\arctan [(1-1/n)x]}{(1-x^2)^{a_n}} \, dx> \frac{1}{n} \cdot\frac{\arctan [(1-1/n)(1-1/n)}{(1-(1-1/n)^2)^{1-1/n}}\\ = \frac{1}{n} \cdot\frac{\arctan (1-1/n)^2}{(1-(1-1/n)^2)^{1-1/n}}$$

Comment: @Partim: No it is just a bounding argument, but I see now I made a mistake with the upper limit of the integral.  I will edit to fix and then explain.

Comment: @Partim: The numerator of the integrand has the lower  bound $\arctan [(1-1/n)x] > \arctan[(1-\frac{1}{n})(1-\frac{1}{n})]$ for $1-\frac{1}{n} \leqslant x \leqslant 1- \frac{1}{2n}$

Comment: Then you can put an upper bound on the denominator with $x = (1-\frac{1}{2n})$ and find the lower bound for the integrand as shown above.  The integral is greater than this lower bound for the integrand times the length of the interval which is $(1 - \frac{1}{2n}) - (1 - \frac{1}{n}) = \frac{1}{2n}$

Answer (score 1):

If you enjoy generalized hypergeometric functions, there is an explicit solution

$$I(a)=\int\limits_{0}^{1}\frac{\tan^{-1} (ax)}{(1-x^2)^a}\, dx \qquad\qquad  \text{with} \qquad  a <1$$

Using the series expansion of the numerator, we then have
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty  (-1)^n\,\frac{a^{2 n+1} }{2 n+1}\,\frac{ x^{2 n+1}}{ \left(1-x^2\right)^{a} }$$
$$\int_0^1 \frac{ x^{2 n+1}}{ \left(1-x^2\right)^{a} }\,dx=\frac{\Gamma (1-a) \,\,\Gamma (n+1)}{2\, \Gamma (n+2-a)}$$
Summing and simplifying
$$\large\color{blue}{I(a)=\frac{a}{2 (1-a)}\,\,\, _3F_2\left(\frac{1}{2},1,1;\frac{3}{2},2-a;-a^2\right)}$$

Expanding around $a=0$

$$I(a)=\frac{a}{2 (1-a)}\left(1-\frac{a^2}{6}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \alpha_n \,a^n\right)$$ where the first coefficients are
$$\left\{1,\frac{1}{2},-\frac{3}{20},-\frac{5}{24},\frac{331}{5040},\frac
  {865}{6048},-\frac{2123}{181440},-\frac{61399}{680400},-\frac{94
   2617}{513216000}\right\} $$  Notice that
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \alpha_n \,a^n=\frac{1+\frac{409 }{798}a+\frac{184 }{665}a^2 }{1+\frac{5 }{399}a+\frac{671 }{1596}a^2 }$$ whose error is $\sim \frac{a^5}{18}$.

This should allow to generate extremely sharp bounds.
Function $I(a)$ goes through a minimum value around $a=-2.95$ and tends to $0^-$ when $a$ tends to $-\infty$.

**Edit**

If $a\to 1^-$, the asymptotic is
$$I(a)=\frac{a \, \pi}{8 (1-a)} +O\left((a-1)\right)$$

Comment: Yes, a good solution method! Only the main problem is finding the integral. If you showed how you calculated the integral and found the hypergeometric function, then my problem could be solved like this

Comment: @Partim. ARe you familiar with these monsters ? By the way, I started this problem five hours ago. Cheers :-)

Comment: Am I familiar with hypergeometric series? Yes, I know them and I can solve many of them. It would be interesting to see the solution to this integral

Also, it would be difficult for me to decompose this series by Taylor, I would also like to see this transformation